# How much would it make sense to post Q&A questions on SE to fill out the Q&A for the IOTA WIKI

Tags: discussion

It could make a ton of sense to let the community gain some reputation here on SE by posting the questions for the Q&A which will be listed on the community wiki at wiki.iota.org. Here is the document with the questions:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wsne-hIXOz3ufsAZNeQVaMy6baYJXbwBncCqoLqHicg/edit

What is the mods opinion on that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't only ask the mods, also the other users here... :)

That being said, in my experience, questions who have subjective or opinion-based answers and/or which don't state a problem of a user (with the answer being the solution for the problem) are a *bad* fit for StackExchange and its reputation system.

While there may be *some* questions on the list that would fit here, in my opinion the majority of them does not (so well).